# How do I populate a select box automatically with values from a IndexedDB objectStore?

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I would like to iterate over a IndexedDB objectStore, get the results and populate this select box.

This is my HTML

```
 <tr>
    <td>
       <select id="opt" name="opt"></select>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

This is my JavaScript

```
function populateOptions() {
  var options = [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
  var opt = document.getElementById("opt");

  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = options[i];
    var optionText = document.createTextNode(options[i]);
    option.appendChild(optionText);
    opt.appendChild(option);
  }

}

populateOptions();
```

Comment: I don't understand, objectStore can be listed by `db.objectStoreNames`  http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBDatabase-objectStoreNames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var dbreq = indexeddb.open("db");
dbreq.onsuccess = function (conn){
    var trans = dbreq.result.transaction(["objectstore"]);
    var obj = trans.objectStore("objectstore");
    var cursor = obj.openCursor();
    cursor.onsuccess = function (e) {
            if (!cursor.result) {
               var opt = document.getElementById("opt"); 
               var option = document.createElement("option");
               option.value = cursor.result.value;                
               var optionText = document.createTextNode(cursor.result.value);                
               option.appendChild(optionText);
               opt.appendChild(option); 
               cursor["continue"]()
            } else {
               // cursor ended
            }
}
```

Or use my [linq2indexeddb library](http://linq2indexeddb.codeplex.com/) and do it like this:

```
var db = linq2indexedDB("db");
db.linq.from("objectstore").select.then(null, null, function(e){
    var opt = document.getElementById("opt"); 
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = e.data;                
    var optionText = document.createTextNode(e.data);                
    option.appendChild(optionText);
    opt.appendChild(option); 

});
```

for more information about indexeddb I can reffer to my [blog](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/search/label/IndexedDB). Here I frequently post information about the indexedDB API.

Comment: Hi Kristof, I've tryed your code and I was getting an error: "TypeError: conn.transaction is not a function"

Comment: I'm trying:
var db;
var req = indexedDB.open("opcoes");
req.onsuccess = function () {
db = req.result;
var tran = db.transaction("vendedores");
tran.objectStore("vendedores").openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
var cursor = event.target.result;
if (cursor) {
var opt = document.getElementById("opt");
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = cursor.result.value;             
var optionText=document.createTextNode(cursor.result.value);
option.appendChild(optionText); opt.appendChild(option);  
}
}
}
But in this case I'm getting: "TypeError: cursor.result is undefined"

Comment: well you got it almost right instead of calling cursor.result.value, you need to call cursor.value. This is because you allready include the result when assigning it to the cursor variable: var cursor = event.target.result. Btw changed the code a bit in my awnser.

Comment: I've tried that too but I only get the first value in the select box...
don't I need a loop to go threw the cursor's results?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot something, you need to call cursor["continue"]() at the end. Note that in your case you will need to call it on event.target

Comment: I think it´s "cursor.continue();" and if I call it before the "if (cursor) {}" it returns undefined

Comment: Sorry, I meant outside of the "if (cursor) {}" function, before or after

Comment: Like in my example above, I changed the code. You need to call it inside the if(cursor.result) at the end

Comment: Finally put it to work!!!
I wasn't putting the value I wanted to reach within the cursor:
option.value = cursor.value."myfield";
Thanks a lot again Kristof, for answering and for sharing your work on your blog and Codeplex etc.
Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

In html :

```
<body onload="load()">
```

In javascript :

```
function load(){
    populateOptions();
}
```

or shortly :

```
<body onload="populateOptions()">
```

Comment: or: <body onload="populateOptions()">
works either way but that's not the issue, thanks anyway Caner Korkmaz.

Comment: I can mark it as useful but it really doesn't solve my problem, the code is working as it is, I just need to use it with a IndexedDB database.

Comment: So the problem now is just iterating over an IndexedDB objectStore and getting the results? [This tutorial explains that part.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB#Using_a_cursor)

Comment: Yes Jeremy that was always the problem, I think I have to create a cursor but I don't know if I have to open the db for that matter or just open a cursor, I'm new to JavaScript and certainly to IndexedDB.
I was going over that page, trying to get it to work,
Thanks.